# Why don't className="flex.." css elements work properly?

Tags: css, reactjs, properties

Here I coded nav bar. but some css properties[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJzTu.jpg) don't work properly in className tag. don't auto suggest when I'm coding there. Please could you help me for this problem.

import Image from "next/image";
import {
MenuIcon,
SearchIcon,
ShoppingCartIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/outline";

function Header() {
return (

{/* Top nev */}

```
                {/* search */}
            <div className="bg-yellow-400 hover">
                <input type="text" />
                <SearchIcon className="h-3 p-4"/>

            </div>

        </div>

        

        {/* Botton nav */}
        <div>

        </div>
    
    </header>
)
```

}

export default Header;

these are not working
;- py-2, mt-2, flex, items-center, flex-grow, sm:flex-grow-0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k42gR.png)

Comment: Could you please share the code and say which properties are not working in your code?

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are using vs code and tailwind

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.